# Postgresql replace function

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

When I do a select like this

```
select
replace(replace(t.field,'{0}',t.parameter01), '{1}', t.parameter02)
from table t
```

I obtain a null result even if t.field contain text without any placeholders. Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: Add Postgres version. Who is e.parameter02??

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.3.3"", edited: it's a t parameter, a column of type char with no value

Comment: Please show us a complete example including sample data (`insert into...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out. If the third parameter of replace function is null, the result will be null although the second one doesn't match anything in the first one. An workaround is to replace the value of third parameter if it is null:

```
select 
replace(t.field, t.parameter01, coalesce(t.parameter02, ''))
from table t
```